# Highlights of cstheory.stackexchange.com

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

To promote this site, it would be useful to have a collection of our highlights. Hence this question:

> **What are the best *technical* questions that have been asked and answered on cstheory.stackexchange.com?**

Rules: One thread per answer. Briefly explain *why* you think it is a highlight. This is CW, please edit the answers to improve them, and vote up/down freely to rank the answers.

Answer (score 3):

#### [A Boolean function that is not constant on affine subspaces of large enough dimension](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1948/a-boolean-function-that-is-not-constant-on-affine-subspaces-of-large-enough-dimen)

A very technical question, with a specific answer. Possibly the exact kind of question that we'd like to see more of.

Answer (score 2):

**[Does Nisan's pseudo-random generator relativize?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2236/)**

Noam Nisan answering a question about his own pseudorandom generator :)

Comment: indeed ! that's a good example. Not sure if the OP realized it though.

Answer (score 1):

#### [Quick encoding of balanced vectors](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/828/quick-encoding-of-balanced-vectors)

Reasons:

- Cute coding theory-ish problem: works great as a puzzle
- Two nice and complete answers.

Answer (score 0):

#### [Approximate counting problem capturing BQP](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1304/approximate-counting-problem-capturing-bqp)

Reasons:

- Very natural and elegant question
- Clean and direct answer
- A recent answer (i.e not something in the canon that a google search would have immediately found)

Comment: I'm not really sure if the OP's question was answered. Firstly, the paper doesn't mention any black-box problems. If we get a black-box problem out under some natural interpretation, I don't see how the problem captures BQP. It seems harder than BQP, but I don't see how it is in BQP. I guess only the OP can tell us if it answers his question or not.