# What is cstheory.stackexchange.com lacking?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

This [question](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383/highlights-of-cstheory-stackexchange-com) asks about the highlights of cstheory.stackexchange.com. Indeed, there have been many. What I'm interesting in knowing is what the non-highlights are. What is lacking from the site? What can be done to improve the situation?

Comment: You are asking two questions.  Both of them are interesting and they are somewhat related to each other, but I would not like to see the answers to two questions mixed up.  Can you break this question into two separate questions?

Comment: Or by “What has been lacking” do you mean “What subfields of TCS have been lacking”?  In that case, it is better not to split the question into two, but if so the question can use a little clarification.

Comment: I can split it into two questions.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to see more

- historical questions
- concurrency, modal logic, reactive systems
- finite model theory, Ehrenfeucht-Fraïssé games, computational logic
- database theory, lower bounds for streaming and sketches
- unconventional models of computation
- pebble automata, bounded verification
- algorithmic graph theory

though this is a purely subjective (and quite rough) list.

Comment: A followup is then: how might we go about getting more questions in these areas.

Comment: I will try to recruit people from Edinburgh (now that I'm based here), which should help to increase the numbers of people interested in these fields.

Answer (score 5):

I like questions regarding "foundations of cryptography" (see [Goldreich's book](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/foc-book.html) regarding the topics it covers).

Apart from the questions I personally asked, I practically saw no one else asking such questions.