# FOCS 2011 cstheory "reporter"

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

[Jeff Atwood encourages us](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/promoting-tcs-se-at-fcrc/1314#1314) to explore support from SE for our conferences. One idea is to pitch a 'FOCS reporter' to attend the conference and write a series of posts for the blog. We could find someone who's attending already, and ideally has some experience writing posts on some blog, and see if we can get their registration covered (and advertise this fact prominently) ?

So the question is: what would be a good way of finding a good candidate, and how should we pitch it to SE ?

Comment: Well, I guess first we need to know who's going, or who's local and would want to go. Then I would suggest prioritizing students.

Comment: We can solicit volunteers: they can nominate themselves in answers below.